# Creating a dynamic breadcrumb with react bootstrap and nextjs. Server error

Tags: next.js, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a dynamic breadcrumb with react bootstrap and nextjs, using <Breadcrumb.Item as={Link}>, but when passing the href={href} property, I get this error: Server Error
Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead.

Child Element:

```
import Link from "next/link"
import { CrumbContainer } from "./styles"
import { Breadcrumb } from "react-bootstrap"
import { BreadcrumbItemProps } from "react-bootstrap"

interface BreadcrumbProps extends BreadcrumbItemProps {
    pag1:string
    pag2?:string 
    pag3?:string 
    href:string 
    href2?:string
}

export default function Crumb({ pag1, pag2 ,pag3, href, href2}:BreadcrumbProps){
    return (
               
              <Breadcrumb>
                { pag1 && !pag2 ?
                  <Breadcrumb.Item active>{pag1}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                
                :
                  pag2 && !pag3  ?
                  <>
                    <Breadcrumb.Item as={Link} href={href}>{pag1}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                    <Breadcrumb.Item active>{pag2}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                  </>
                :
                   pag3 && 
                    <>
                      <Breadcrumb.Item as={Link} href={href}>{pag1}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                      <Breadcrumb.Item as={Link} href={href2}>{pag2}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                      <Breadcrumb.Item active>{pag3}</Breadcrumb.Item>
                    </>
                  }
              </Breadcrumb>
                 
    )
}
```

Exemple of usage:

```
import Crumb from "@/components/Crumb";


export default function Isrc(){
    return (
        <div>
            <Crumb 
              href="/services" 
              pag1="Serviçes" 
              pag2="Generate ISRC/ECAD" 
            />
        </div>

      REST OF THE PAGE...

    )
}
```

error generated:

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Failed prop type: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead.
Open your browser's console to view the Component stack trace.

it works perfectly fine if I don't use Link, but I don't want unnecessary reloads on the page.

By the way, reloading the same page on next without the Link, it generates a styling problem